# passing PHP input value as a string into innerText of a Javascript document and getting dynamically echoed

Tags: javascript, php, post, innerhtml

I am trying to build a simple game of two players where player names comes through an input form. In every turn respective player's name is dynamically displayed. Here is an extract from the **index.php**

> ```
> <?php
> if (isset($_POST['startButton'])) {
>   $p1 = $_POST['playername1'];
>   $p2 = $_POST['playername2'];
> }
> ?>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <script src="script.js" defer></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <div class="leadboard">
>       <div class="turn" id="pturn">
>         <div data-player-turn-text></div>
>       </div>
>       <form class="" id="playform" method="post">
>         <div class="login" id="players">
>           <input type="text" id="playername1" placeholder="player 1">
>           <input type="text" id="playername2" placeholder="player 2">
>           <button type="button" name="button" id="startButton">ok</button>
>         </div>
>       </form>
> </body>
> </html>
>
> <?php  ?>
> ```

in **script.js** I declare a variable *oTurn* which when true indicates `'playername1'`'s turn and else `playername2` 's turn.
below is the extract

> ```
> const playerTurnTextElement=document.querySelector('[data-player-turn-text]')
> let oTurn
> .
> .
> .
> playerTurnTextElement.innerHTML = oTurn ? '<?php echo json_encode($p1) ; ?>' : '<?php echo json_encode($p2) ; ?>';
> ```

The output comes blank whether I use `json_encode()` or not. 
Going to developer's tool I find the whole innerHTML is being commented out.

> ```
> <div class="turn" id="pturn">
>         <div data-player-turn-text>
>             <!--?php echo json_encode($p2) ; ?-->
>         </div>
>   </div>
> ```

Also if I use `playerTurnTextElement.innerText` to assign, the correct option as per the respective turn is passed entirely as a string and displayed including all tags and symbols.

Somewhere I read I cannot use javascript to dynamic load php files. Is this relevant? What is the way to get this done? 
*I can share the complete code if required however this works fine if we pass a fixed string instead of trying to dynamically pass POST values.*

Comment: Does script.js get parsed by the php parser?  Probably not (usually only files ending with php do).  I'm not sure that would help anyway.  Stage 1, browser requests some php file, and the php parser builds the output and serves it to the client as html/javascript.  Stage 2, html/javascript read and processed by the browser.  You can't do "php things" in stage 2.

Comment: the entire logic of the game is built on the script.js file and the output to the screen keeps changing with each turn of the game. only the javascript file cannot access the php value input via POST method.

Comment: Yeah it's because blocks of PHP script in JS files (like `<?php echo json_encode($p2) ?>` don't get processed by php at all.